# Java: if/else statement in infinite loop not working

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to figure out why my function isn't working as it should. The code is fairly basic and self explanatory. Here is the function:

```
public static void Greet(){
    System.out.println("Hello, what is your name? ");
    name = scan.nextLine();
    do{
        System.out.println("Would you like to order some coffee, " + name + "? (y/n) ");
        input = scan.nextLine();
        if(input == "y"){
            System.out.println("Great! Let's get started.");
            break;
        }
        else if(input == "n"){
            System.out.println("Come back next time, " + name + ".");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Invalid response. Try again.");
        }
    }
    while(true);
}
```

Basically, regardless of what I enter as "input" on line 5, the function will treat it as if I hadn't entered a 'y' or 'n', it just constantly loops the while(true) and printing "Invalid response. Try again." I have no idea why my if/else statements aren't working correctly. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `break` will break you out of the loop

Comment: change `input == "y"` to `"y".equals(input)`

Comment: I have a break on line 9, but that isn't the problem. The problem is regardless of what I input, it consistently loops to the final 'else' statement.

Comment: I replaced `input == "y"` and `input == "n"` with `"y".equalsIgnoreCase(input)` and `"n".equalsIgnoreCase(input)` and it seems to work fine for me

Comment: @MadProgrammer my bad - please ignore

Comment: @JasperSquire Before asking questions first you need to read Java fundamental basics and learn how to compare string or char and what is difference between "==" and equals() method.

Comment: Thanks guys, yeah it works when I replace 'input == "y"' with '(input.trim()).equals("y"))' Wow it's amazing how the smallest errors can make me sit for hours on end trying to find a solution. StackOverflow you are my hero

Comment: @Ranjeet In my classes, we haven't learnt the equals() method, we're still using "==" so that's why I relied on it. I've learnt from my mistake though, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare String by `equals` not by `==`

```
if((input.trim()).equals("y")){
```

`equals` compares the value
`==` comapres the reference

Answer (score 0):

Compare with `equals`.

```
if(input.equals("y")){
            System.out.println("Great! Let's get started.");
            break;
        }
        else if(input.equals("n")){
            System.out.println("Come back next time, " + name + ".");
            System.exit(0);
        }
```